# Residue of $\frac{1}{z^2-9}$ at $z=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

A question on an exam asks to find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-9}$ at $z=3$.

This is how i solved it:

$f(z)$ is in the form $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ so $\operatorname{Res}(f,3) = \frac{p(3)}{q'(3)}$.

$\operatorname{Res}(f,3)=\frac{1}{(2\cdot(3))}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Am I correct? seems to be very easy for an exam question.

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's good that you find it easy!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Since $f $ has a simple pole at $z=3$: $$\operatorname*{Res}(f,3)=\lim_{z \to 3} (z-3)\frac{1}{z^2-9}=\lim_{z\to 3} \frac {z-3}{(z-3)(z+3)}=\lim_{z \to 3}\frac {1}{z+3}=\frac{1}{6} $$

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. You could also have used partial fraction decomposition and the definition of residue:$$\frac1{z^2-9}=\frac1{(z-3)(z+3)}=\frac16\left(\frac1{z-3}-\frac1{z+3}\right)$$and therefore$$\operatorname{res}_3\frac1{z^2-9}=\frac16\left(\operatorname{res}_3\frac1{z-3}+\operatorname{res}_3\frac1{z+3}\right)=\frac16(1+0)=\frac16.$$